# CSS equal height of div

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, equals

I have a page with 3 div that I want to have the same height. ***The thing is that they don't have background*** .

Here is what I have (3 columns with some content in it):
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wahQH.png)

Here is what I need:
 [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqsjs.png)

**In red:** the 3 columns.

**In green:** the div that need to have a dynamic height

**So I would like the div into the green box to have the same size as the green box to make the red div in the same height as others divs. How to achieve that ?**

Comment: include your css and html

Comment: Use `display:flex;`